# "You need to add an icon to your apk"

Tags: c#, android, google-play, apk, android-manifest

I've looked through other articles on here and gone through what they've all advised but to no avail. Every time I try to upload my `APK` for `alpha testing` on `google play` I get this same error message:

> You need to add an icon to your APK.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but if anybody could help me that would be much appreciated.

Here's a copy of my `AndroidManifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.sdkbox.activity.CustomActivity" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.sdkbox.activity.CustomActivity.CustomActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.android.view.UnityAdsFullscreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: What image format is your `app_icon`? I think just png or jpg are acceptable

Comment: with our app, the app icon lies in the mipmap folder with a .png extension. So in the manifest it looks like : "android:icon="@mipmap/ic_android_mobile_app"

Comment: @DavidMedenjak the file's a .png, not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Smashing thanks for the suggestion, but I've checked that the file is in the drawable folder

Comment: do you have your icon in the `drawable-*dpi` folders and *not* in some localized, orientation, ... version of it?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak yeah the icons in the drawable, drawable-hdpi, -ldpi, -xhdpi, -xxhdpi and the -xxxhpi folders

Comment: Try adding a mipmap-mdpi folder inside your res folder and adding it in there. Not inside the drawable folder!.

Comment: @Smashing thanks, but still no joy. Really not sure what the problem is here